# Access data from ajax success in complete?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way that I can access the data I receive during success so i can use it during the complete callback?

Or perhaps there is a way where i can assign multiple success functions?

What i need is, to allow success callback to be changed based on situation, but I need to always perform a dedicated function on success using the same data that was returned to the first function.

I suppose i can always setup my call like so, but i'm looking to see if there is a better way.

```
CallServer = function(options) {
  if(options.success) {
    var customSuccess = options.success;
    options.success = function(data) {
      defaultSuccess(data);
      customSuccess(data);
    }
  }
  $.extend(true, defaults, options);
  $.ajax(defaults);
}
```

**EDIT:** I have found my answer. I didn't realize that the xhr holds the data as the responseText. so the following gets me the same thing that gets returned as 'data' on success.

```
complete: function(xhr){dosomething(xhr.responseText);}
```

and that's it! Thanks

Comment: Since you seem to be using jQuery already, read up on jQuery's [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) functionality. You can add multiple callbacks using the `.done()` method.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I can imagine it being useful later on in my project. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be able to help with getting the returned data of an ajax call into it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my answer. I didn't realize that the xhr holds the data as the responseText. so the following gets me the same thing that gets returned as 'data' on success.

```
complete: function(xhr){dosomething(xhr.responseText);}
```

and that's it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, the success callback accepts the data as its first argument.

From the jQuery Documentation ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ) the argument list for the success callback is:

> success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)

As far as I am aware, there is no built-in way to add multiple success callbacks, but you could easily dispatch any number of functions from a custom success callback.

Perhaps you could use a system like:

```
function customSuccess(data) {
    if (situation == "one way") {
        firstFunction(data):
    }
    else if (situation == "another way") {
        secondFunction(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but my question is if i can get the data object returned to the success function to be accessible to the complete function that gets run afterward, so that I do not have to do a situational success function.

Comment: In my example it is being passed to the dispatched function as an argument. Is this what you mean?